# What is ÿþC when opening archives?

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to read a file using `fopen` followed by `fscanf` in MATLAB. Its first three lines are:

```
Cell 1  1   12/8/2002 09:20 31.07
Cell 1  2   12/8/2002 09:30 31.07
Cell 1  3   12/8/2002 09:40 31.07
```

So, at first I tried to do the following:

```
[fileID,erro] = fopen('corr_demo.txt','r');
[vel]=fread(fileID, '%s %d %s %d %s %d %s %f');
```

But the vector `vel`, which is `[1 x 4]`, shows nothing but "ÿþC" and the other three columns are empty.
Then I tried using `dlmread`, and the vector `vel` is `[255 254 67 0 101 0 108 0 108 0]`. Then I tried using `char(vel)`, which gives me `ÿþC e l l`. So, again, the same character.
Could anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: 0xFFFE (your ÿþ) is a byte order mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
[fileID,erro] = fopen('corr_demo.txt','r');
[vel]=textscan(fileID, '%s %d %s %d %s %d %s %f');
```

The reason [`fread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) does not work, is because `fread` reads data from a *binary file*. What you have there as your data is a *text file*.
See it this way: you want to eat soup. The correct utensil to eat that would be a spoon, but you attempt to eat it using a knife. The knife in this example would be `fread`, the spoon [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

Also I found [this](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16493-textscan-or-import-of-unicode-encoded-textfile) thread explaining in more detail what a Byte Order Mark is and why it gave you an error.

As suggested by @NeryNeto, it needed to be added that the file is actually in `Unicode`. `r` sets is to read and `n` forces it to use system byte ordering. The last two switches are actually optional, since they are the defaults of `fopen`

```
fid = fopen([caminho '\' arquivo],'r','n','Unicode');
```

Comment: Presumably `textscan` recognizes the UTF-16 and `fread` reads bytes.

Comment: I'm sorry, Chris, but I don't get it how could I fix this. textscan doesn't work aswell, giving the same ÿþC error

Comment: @NeryNeto I if your data is exactly as presented in your example this is the way to go. This worked fine using MATLAB 2012a on a 64 bits Windows 7 machine. I even copied your file to extent 300 rows and it worked.

Comment: Thank you Visser. I found out how to fix the problem, but I am still studying the reason. This file is a software's output, and encoded as Unicode. When I save the same file but encoded as ANSI it works well. Could you explain me better? thank you

Comment: @NeryNeto I read the documentation on fread (which usually is the first step on getting an error) and updated my answer.

Comment: I finally found out how to solve it. Instead of using fid = fopen([caminho '\' arquivo]); I used fid = fopen([caminho '\' arquivo],'r','n','Unicode');

Comment: I'll add it to the answer so it is collected. Good find.